# How do you prove $A_1\rightarrow A_{n+1}$ if $A_1\rightarrow A_2$ , $A_2\rightarrow A_3$ , ... , $A_n\rightarrow A_{n+1}$ are true?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I think I can prove it this way, when $A_1$ is false then no matter what $A_1\rightarrow A_{n+1}$ is true so when $A_1$ is true matters to us. When $A_1$ is true, since $A_1\rightarrow A_2$ is true then $A_2$ is true too, when $A_2$ is true, since $A_2\rightarrow A_3$ is true then $A_3$ is true too , ... ,  when $A_n$ is true, since $A_n\rightarrow A_{n+1}$ is true then $A_{n+1}$ is true too; so overall we can conclude that when $A_1$ is true then $A_{n+1}$ is true too and this proves $A_1\rightarrow A_{n+1}$.

Now how do you prove it and is there anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: Your proof is informally fine. If you want to be very precise you'll want to prove what is hidden in the "..." formally by using induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you refer to is known as induction. It is a property of the natural numbers. In a set theoretic setup, it simply states that if $S \subseteq \mathbb N$ such that $1 \in \mathbb N$ and $n \in S \implies (n+1) \in S$ then $S = \mathbb N$. This can be shown to be equivalent to your statement, by letting S be the set of natural numbers such that $A_n$ is true. Then from what you state and the set theoretic induction hypothesis, $A = \mathbb N$, or in other words $A_n$ holds true $\forall n \in \mathbb N$, given that $A_1$ holds true. Thus $A_1 \implies A_n, \forall n \in \mathbb N$.